# JAX-RS2 client response filter for bad connection error cases

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, resteasy, jersey-client

In JAX-RS2 based clients there are two extension points for request processing: `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter` and `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseFilter`. Both of them will be invoked while on a happy path. But when there's a connectivity issue (connection timeout, the connection is closed by the host, connection reset). You'll get a `ProcessingException` thrown and none of the response filter's code will be invoked.

Which, in our case, will lead to some metrics not being sent. I was wondering if there's a way that I don't know about to subscribe to any possible failures from the client? Ideally, being able to access to `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext` because some of our related state is stored there.

Or is there another way you addressed this issue?

A bit of code to illustrate the problem:

```
class SomeClient {
  private WebTarget client;

  //...

  public String doGet() {
    return client
        .register((ClientRequestFilter) requestContext -> {
            System.out.println("REQUEST");
        })
        .register((ClientResponseFilter) (requestContext, reponseContext) -> {
            System.out.println("RESPONSE"); // On connection closed path this will never be invoked
        })
        .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
        .get();
  }
}
```

Comment: Alex, I stumbled on your post, and have the same use-case. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SevaSafris nah, I moved away from Jersey. I know that Jersey 3 came out these days. Haven't checked it, no idea if anything is different there.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your response. Looking at [JAX-RS 3.0 Spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.0#client_api), I believe support for this use-case is still missing. What seems to be needed is something resembling the Server API's `ExceptionMapper`, but for the Client API.